# My company has been acquired by another company, am in an agreement with my company!

Tags: management, human-resources, contracts, india, employment-agreement

This is the point mentioned in my agreement regarding acquisitions, but I cannot understand this clearly. Does this mean I'll be forced to continue my agreement with acquired company, or can I relieve from this agreement and leave my job? I have 1 year of agreement remaining.

> In the event that my employment is transferred by X, to a subsidiary
>   or affiliated company,My employment with such company will, for the
>   purpose of this agreement, be considered as continued employment by X,
>   unless and until I execute an agreement, substantially similar in
>   substance to this agreement, then in force in any such company for
>   which I become employed.

X is my company name.

Comment: This is a specific legal question about a specific clause in a specific contract. You need to ask a qualified lawyer.

Comment: Voting to close because it is a pure legal question. Not only must the above statement be understood, but so does the nature of the acquisition. They could be merging, they could remain a wholly own subsidiary, or they could be buying the technology and firing all the workers....

Comment: The only thing that the clause quoted above does is confirm that your employment duration is retained if you transfer to the new company (this might also allow you to keep duration related benefits (for example, holiday entitlement).

Comment: Am not exactly asking for legal opinion, it is about interpretation.

Comment: Interpretation *is* legal opinion. "Does this clause in my contract mean X?" is a question that only your lawyer (or maybe your HR department) can give you a definitive answer to.

Comment: If your company was acquired, I'm not sure the acquiring company would count as "subsidiaryor affiliated company", ask a lawyer

Comment: Whether it is legal for them to make you sign a new agreement or not, if you want to continue your employment at that company, you should sign unless the new agreement is such that no one would sign it. It may be possible to negotiate a little, but in an acquisition you have little room for negotiations unless you are senior manager. Refusal will likely put you on the "position no longer needed" list. If you choose not to sign, immediately start looking for another job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, according to the clause you have quoted, your employment agreement will considered to still be active and in force even after transfer to another entity, unless you subsequently sign a similar agreement with the new company.

In other words, an acquisition doesnt void your agreement.

Comment: Downvoting because there is *nowhere near* enough context to offer an accurate legal opinion. And because answering clearly Off-Topic questions should be discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, 
My company is asking me to sign in a new agreement with the new company,Is it mandatory for me to sign?.
They want me to resign from X company and join Y. Do i have to?

Comment: @Thickar well, that all depends on your local laws - here in the EU we have TUPE to manage employee contractual obligations after transfers to new entities, and I have no idea what your local laws are.  Not only does that constitute a new question (and should be asked separately) but its also something that requires a lot more legal interpretation than your original question, and as such will probably be closed as such.

Comment: @Thickar *Ask a lawyer*, or maybe your HR department.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In this case, I disagree. "What does this clause in my contract mean in the context of this merger?" is, IMO, about as clear an Off-Topic question as you can get.

Comment: It's not a legal question. It has nothing to do with laws. The question is what a rather complicated sentence means. It means exactly what the sentence says, it's just a bit hard to understand, which is why people ask for help understanding it.

Comment: Interpretation of the clause is absolutely a legal opinion since lawyer will define if very clearly ig/when OP gets sued for breach of contract. Let's try not to get attached to questions when the **right** thing to do is to avoid giving unqualified advice.

Comment: A lawyers opinion is no more or less valid than anyone elses in these situations, since a lawyers opinion is not a ruling on the interpretation - only a judges opinion is actually any more relevant, so I feel completely justified in giving my own common sense interpretation of a rather obvious clause.  I dont care if you think that the only interpretation possible is legal and therefor inadmissible, as thats why Stack Exchange has a bad rep these days - way way too many things being closed too quickly in precisely these situations.

Comment: And who gets to define the *right* thing here...?

Comment: @Moo You're right that a lawyer's legal opinion isn't binding, and may be wrong. But *if* it's wrong, you can sue them into the ground for failing to understand the law. It's a rather higher bar than "this makes sense to me, therefore that is probably how a court would see it".